# Tracing the last tag?

Tags: svn, tags, tortoisesvn, branch

I have the trunk created in the repository. Now I have created a development branch and branched it off from the trunk. Lets say at this point, branch is at revision 500. I create a tag from revision 500. Now I keep making updates on this branch, and it reaches revision 600. Now when I create a tag, I need to include revisions 501-600. This is something that needs to be done manually. But I have a script which crawls the svn logs for the revision numbers I provide. Like I say 
`crawl.bat "tag name" revision_start revison_end` . 
Now this process needs to be automated. Like I just have to say `crawl.bat "tag name"` and it should find out the last revision where tag was created from, and put it in revision_start. Are there any svn commands to do what I intend to do? Like to find out last revision which created a tag?

Answer (score 0):

- I can understand your "base" trouble: if you want to create tag from revision 600 (which is HEAD of $BRANCH), **just create it**, from branch

> This is something that needs to be done manually

It seems you have a Big Blackhole in the knowledge about Subversion and SCMs in common - each revision (changeset) is a **full state** of repository at the some moment, it contain all changes, happened in the past, i.e

**When you tag from  branch's HEAD, this new branch's files will have all changes (500-600), introduced in branch after previous tagging**

- Anyway, you have at least 2 methods of getting revision of $TAG: with `ls` or `log`

### LS-way

```
svn ls $REPO-URL/tags/$TAG -v
  7 abream                окт 17  2012 ./
  3 teno                0 окт 17  2012 core_mod.txt
```

First field in string of `./` is revision of this tag

*or*

```
svn ls $REPO-URL/tags/ -v
      7 abream                окт 17  2012 ./
      4 teno                  окт 17  2012 $TAG/
      7 abream                окт 17  2012 $ANOTHERTAG/
```

First field in string of $TAG is revision of this tag

### LOG-way

```
svn log $REPO-URL/tags/$TAG -q --stop-on-copy
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r7 | abream | 2012-10-17 22:14:36 +0600 (Ср, 17 окт 2012)
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

first data field in output (before "|") is revision number, prepended with `r` char

Comment: [svn info](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html) would also do the job and is easier to parse/read.

Comment: @Lazy badger: Maybe my question wasnt clear enough because thr is NO big blackhole in my knowledge about subversion. When I say I wanted to include revisions from 500-600, I meant svn logs from 500-600 only. Even though for me it was clear in the question, but I can see where it can be interpreted otherwise

Comment: @UnderDog - OK, for *this* task  I'll suggest store last tagpoint as svn-property (of trunk?) and read it with propget

Comment: Can you please explain in bit detail? You mean adding a comment while creating a tag? Sorry I am not aware about propget function. Probably I should read more about it